# response of 1st request should be used as header request for 2nd one

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a issue in writing a code in jmeter where it is a adaptive way(i.e., response of 1st request should be used as header request for 2nd one) should use bean shell and writer coding and this should be done for n number of request fetching every request's response data and using it in next request

In previous response- is= 26c0745
In request - GUID:26c0745

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid scripting and use JMeter's built-in components where possible. Also [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).

So I would recommend using [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor) for extracting the header:

[image]

and then in the next request you will be able to use `${number}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) reference where required.